# How to test routes that don't include controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, testunit

I'm using minitest in Rails to do testing, but I'm running into a problem that I hope a more seasoned tester can help me out with because I've tried looking everywhere for the answer, but it doesn't seem that anyone has run into this problem or if they have, they opted for an integration test.

Let's say I have a controller called `Foo` and action in it called `bar`. So the `foo_controller.rb` file looks like this:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def bar
    render 'bar', :layout => 'application'
  end 
end
```

The thing is that I don't want people to access the "foo/bar" route directly. So I have a route that is `get 'baz' => 'foo#bar'`.

Now I want to test the FooController:

```
require 'minitest_helper'

class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def test_should_get_index
    get '/baz'
  end
end
```

But the test results in an error that `No route matches {:controller=>"foo", :action=>"/baz"}`. How do I specify the controller for the GET request?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. It's been very hard for me to find the answer.

Comment: Don't bother testing it directly. It's an implementation detail of your controller. Test the publicly accessible actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to test thus:

**With Rails 3:**

```
require 'minitest_helper'

class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def test_should_get_index
    assert_routing "/baz", :controller => "foo", :action => "bar"
  end
end
```

**With Rails 4:**

```
require "test_helper"

class FooControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_should_get_index
    assert_generates "/baz", :controller => "foo", :action => "bar"
  end
end
```

Comment: just a note, assert_routing still works in [rails 4](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_routing)